# Closed subsets of a compact metric space with distance zero from each other

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, metric-spaces, compactness

I am currently taking a Metric Spaces course, and during an activity, I had to prove the following result:

*Let $(X,d)$ be a compact metric space and $A,B \subset X$ two closed subsets such that $d(A,B)=0$. Then $A \cap B \neq \emptyset$.*

My reasoning was the following. Using the fact that $d(A,B) = 0$, for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$, we may obtain $a_n \in A$ and $b_n \in B$ such that $d(a_n,b_n) < \frac1n$. This gives us two sequences $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \subset A$ and $(b_m)_{m \in \mathbb{N}}\subset B$ with the property that for every $\epsilon>0$, there is a natural number $n_0$ such that $d(a_n,b_n) < \epsilon$ for every $n \geq n_0$.

From the compactness of $X$ we obtain a subsequence $(a_{n_k})_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ of $(a_n)$ which converges to some point $a \in X$. We know that in fact $a \in A$ because $A$ is closed. Now the claim is that $a \in A \cap B$. To show this, it is sufficient to show that $a \in \overline{B}$.

For any real number $r>0$ we know that there exists an $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $d(a_n,b_n)< \frac r2$ for every $n \geq n_0$, and from the convergence of the subsquence $(a_{n_k})$, there exists and $n_{k_0} \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $d(a,a_{n_k}) < \frac r2$ for every $n_k \geq n_{k_0}$. Then, taking any $n_k \geq \max\{n_0,n_{k_0}\}$ we have

$$d(a,b_{n_k}) \leq d(a,a_{n_k})+d(a_{n_k},b_{n_k}) < \frac r2 + \frac r2 = r,$$

so that $b_{n_k}$ lies in the open ball of radius $r$ centered in $a$, thus showing that $a \in \overline{B}$.

While I was discussing my attempt of proof with the person that was applying the activity, she claimed that it was not correct because I had to be more careful when using the indexes of the subsequence $(a_{n_k})$ to identify specific terms of the sequence $(b_n)$ as I did in the last inequality above. She argued that I should first consider the sequence $(b_{n_k})_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ with the same indices of the subsequence $(a_{n_k})$, obtain a convergent subsequence of $(b_{n_k})$ and then use this new subsequence during the proof. I didn't really understand why this would be necessary or what is the problem with the argument above.

So I would like some help to know if what I did is correct, or to understand where is the problem if the proof happens to be wrong. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your proof is correct. If $a_{n_k}$ converges, so will $b_{n_k}$, to the same point. Good observation. Moreover, it  is enough to assume $A$ compact, and $B$ closed, by your observation.

Comment: This is correct but too complicated. Just use the fact that a continuous function on a compact space attains it's minimum plus the fact that product of two compacts is compact.

Comment: As @MoisheCohen pointed out, the proof can be shortened if one knows the two facts cited in his comment  plus the fact that the distance function is continuous with respect to the product topology. I would, however, expect that, at the stage of study where this exercise occurs, not all of those facts have been established.

Answer (score 2):

This is a long comment to illustrate a slightly different method. It uses some  results that you might not be familiar with.

1. For any metric space $(U,e)$ and $\phi\ne V\subset U,$ the function $f(u)=\inf\{e(u,v):v\in V\}=e(u,V)$ is continuous from $U$ to $\Bbb R.$ The proof is elementary.
2. The continuous image of a compact space is compact.  The proof is elementary. And for a  subspace $A$ of a compact Hausdorff space $X$ (for example, when $X$ a compact metric space) we have: $A$ is compact iff $A$ is closed in $X$.
3. So in your Q, assuming $A\ne \phi \ne B$, the function $f_A(a)=d(a,B)$ for $a\in A$ is continuous from $A$ to $\Bbb R $. So $f_A(A)$  is a compact non-empty subset of $\Bbb R$  and therefore $\min f_A(A)$ exists.

If $\min f_A(A)=r>0$ then $\forall a\in A\;\forall b\in B\;(d(a,b)\geq r)$, that is, $d(A,B)\geq r>0.$

If $\min f_A(A)=0$ then  there exists $a_0$ in $A$ with $f_A(a_0)=0.$ That is $\inf \{d(a_0,b):b\in B\}=0.$  So every open ball of positive radius, centered at $a_0,$ contains a member of $B.$ So $a_0\in \overline B=B.$

Remark. If $C,D$ are closed non-compact subsets of a metric space $(Y,e)$ it may be that $\inf \{e(a,b):a\in A,\;b\in B\}=0$ and $A\cap B=\phi.$ For example let $Y=\Bbb R$ with $e(x,y)=|x-y|.$ Let $A=\Bbb Z^+$ and $B=\{n+2^{-n}: n\in \Bbb Z^+\}.$